# Restoring matplotlib to default after using style sheets

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, stylesheet

I've been using Python for only two weeks, and everything was going great until today.

A coworker told me about style sheets, so I tried out ggplot. It was OK, but I liked my plots better, so I tried to go back to my default settings. I did some research, and tried to following:

**First try**

```
mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
```

**Second try**

```
matplotlib.rcdefaults()
```

**Third try (this one's for iPython but I'm desperate so I tried it**

```
inline_rc = dict(mpl.rcParams)

mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)

mpl.rcParams.update(inline_rc)
```

And nothing. Yes, the plot changed, but now the background is gray and the colors are still the same as when I used ggplot.

Some more background: My matplotlib version is 1.4.3, I'm using Python 2.7, and Spyder for Mac, Spyder-Py2.

Thanks!

Comment: I faced a similar problem when I used `seaborn` to plot graphs. The problem is solved once you restart your `iPython`